# How to edit style in react-bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using [this boilerplate](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) to create a react based application. I have this basic code:

App.js:

```
 render() {
    const styles = require('./App.scss');
    return (
      <div className="styles.app">
        <Helmet {...config.app.head}/>
        <Navbar fixedTop className={styles.navbar}>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <IndexLink to="/" activeStyle={{color: '#33e0ff'}}>
                <div className={styles.brand}/>
              </IndexLink>
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle/>
          </Navbar.Header>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

App.scss:

```
.app {
  .navbar{
    background: #1b6d85;
  }
  .brand {
    position: absolute;
    $size: 40px;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #2d2d2d;
    width: $size;
    height: $size;
    background-size: 80%;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    border-radius: $size / 2;
  }
  nav :global(.fa) {
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
}
.appContent {
  margin: 50px 0; // for fixed navbar
}
```

For the `Navbar` tag, I tried using both `className` as was done in the template and `bsStyle` as I saw in some questions online. I havent been able to successfully edit any component of react-bootstrap. 
If I have missed the documentation of this in react-bootstrap website, please point me to it too. Thanks.

Comment: Have you added bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js as dependency in your index.html

Comment: No, I didn't know if it was required for adding style into react-bootstrap. Can you please provide some reference?

Answer (score 1):

`React-bootstrap` requires `bootstrap.css` as a dependency in your file. Add it in your `index.html` and it should work fine for you.

See this documentation:

[React-bootstrap guide](https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=467&mlid=0_1&id=kzwpWNXJCNOPjgTIvanABQ&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1479097491&sig=AF9NedkWV5psUecgtknwSGfjB9zkN0J--A)

Comment: I am on mobile so it's difficult for me to write a detail explanation. But the link in the answer should help you

Comment: I think that you should check out the boilerplate that I mentioned. It works a bit differently and I think it has bootstrap configured in it.

Comment: What I could understand from the documentation is that they are using local styles and so you can try to import bootstrap.min.css in you file after downloading it. Also in order to directly specify the styles and not explicitly mention them make the required changes mentioned in readme.md file

Comment: You shouldn't need bootstrap.js. The whole point of React-Bootstrap is to allow for Bootstrap's styling with idiomatic React. That's not possible with bootstrap.js.

Comment: @mattsmith I agree bootstrap.js is not required but stylesheet is. As mentioned ed in the react doc